# xdomain implementation for angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xdomainrequest

I'm developing an angular application that executes ajax calls to web services to get/post data. The issue is that my app runs under a secure protocol (https), but the services are exposed using a non secure protocol (http) so everytime it tries to get/post data Ithe console shows this message: "`Mixed content: the page https://myappdev.abcdomain.com/app/index.html was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myservice-a-bus.abcdomain.com/moduleUserApp/verifyUser'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`" I found this is related to Cross-Domain Resources and that the [xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) patch would fix it. So I tried implementing it but I can't figure out where to add the proxy.html file. Below is where my app is and some of the services I call:

Angular app is

```
https://myappdev.abcdomain.com/app/index.html
```

The services I call are (get/post):

```
http://myservice-a-bus.abcdomain.com/moduleUserApp/verifyUser
http://myservice-b-bus.abcdomain.com/moduleFriendList/get/{"friendList": "ListA"}
http://myservice-c-bus.abcdomain.com/moduleCountryList/get/{"countryList": "Canada"}
```

Hope anyone can help with this issue.

Comment: use your server as proxy to make the requests